# Convergence of random variables in $L^1$

Tags: probability, limits, convergence-divergence, stochastic-processes, random-variables

So $g$ is a continuous real-valued function and are given that the sequence of random variables $Y_n$ converges to $Y$ in $L^1$, $E[|g(Y_n)|]<\infty$ and $E[|g(Y)|]<\infty$. Show that $g(Y_n)$ also converges to $g(Y)$ in $L^1$.

So I need to show that $E[|g(Y_n)-g(Y)|]\rightarrow0$. Any hints what I could use? Thanks!

Comment: Show the result for indicators, then approximate any continuous bounded function with indicators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks false. Suppose the pdf on $\mathbb {R}$ is $p(x)=\frac{1}{\pi(1+x^2)}$ and $Y_n = n\chi_{[n,n+1/n^2]}.$ Then $Y_n\to 0$ in $L^1(p(y)dy).$ Define $g(y) = e^y.$ Then $g\circ Y_n = e^n\chi_{[n,n+1/n^2]},$ whose $L^1(p(y)dy)$ norms are finite but $\to \infty.$

Comment: The concatenation looks wrong to me. Just consider that $exp$ is never zero while the claimed expression for the concatenation is zero on a set of positive measure. Why don't you take Lebesgue measure on the unit interval and use more or less the same construction? Looks cleaner to me...

Comment: Yes, I should have written $g\circ Y_n \ge e^n\chi_{[n,n+1/n^2]}.$ And I think you're right, an analogous example on $[0,1]$ would have been simpler.